# Oracle PL/SQL : Return date based on the day for sysdate in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have a requirement where i have to pick data from DB based on start_date and end_date passed to it.

- If sysdate is sunday then function should return start_date as date on saturday in YYYYMMDD format and end_date as date on saturday in YYYYMMDD format.
- If sysdate is monday then start_date should be date on saturday and end_date should be of sunday.
- If sysdate is tuesday then start_date should be date on saturday and end_date will be of monday..and so on..

How will a function look like to return two dates in YYYYMMDD format based on req.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, first you say that the function needs two entry data: start_date and end_date, and then you say to return two dates with conditions based on the current date. Do you want the function to return start_date and end_date modified to another dates depending on current date? Or do you want to calculate start_date and end_date based only on current date, and you don't pass to the function any dates as entry data?

Comment: Following my previous comment, if you are trying the first option I stated previously, what date do you want as output for your data, the same date or nearest previous saturday for start_date, for example, if start_date 2021/11/18 (thursday) as output for start_date you want 20211113 or the next available saturday: 20211120 in my example. What happens if start_date is Saturday (2021/11/13) and current_date is Saturday? Similar questions for end_date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that start date is always Saturday, while end date is a *day previous to sysdate*.

If that's so, here's how:

My database speaks Croatian so I'm switching to English (and setting default date format, just to show what *sysdate* is); you don't have to do that.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

The `TEMP` CTE *mimics* sysdate change. `next_day` function searches for Saturday previous to `sysdate`.

21.11.2021 is Sunday, so you want to get 20.11.2021 as start and end dates:

```
SQL> with temp as (select date '2021-11-21' sys_date from dual)
  2  select
  3    sys_date,
  4    to_char(next_day(sys_date, 'SATURDAY') - 7, 'yyyymmdd') as start_date,
  5    to_char(sys_date - 1, 'yyyymmdd') as end_date
  6  from temp;

SYS_DATE   START_DA END_DATE
---------- -------- --------
21.11.2021 20211120 20211120
```

23.11.2021 is Tuesday, so you want to get Saturday as start date and Monday as end date:

```
SQL> with temp as (select date '2021-11-23' sys_date from dual)
  2  select
  3    sys_date,
  4    to_char(next_day(sys_date, 'SATURDAY') - 7, 'yyyymmdd') as start_date,
  5    to_char(sys_date - 1, 'yyyymmdd') as end_date
  6  from temp;

SYS_DATE   START_DA END_DATE
---------- -------- --------
23.11.2021 20211120 20211122

SQL>
```

---

In reality, you'd just

```
SQL> select
  2    sysdate,
  3    to_char(next_day(sysdate, 'SATURDAY') - 7, 'yyyymmdd') as start_date,
  4    to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyymmdd') as end_date
  5  from dual;

SYSDATE    START_DA END_DATE
---------- -------- --------
18.11.2021 20211113 20211117

SQL>
```